# Haskell: Tail of a String "a"

Tags: string, haskell, tail

Why is the tail of a String with only one letter the empty String and not the empty List?

Example:

```
tail "a"
= ""
```

But you can create a String as:

```
'a' : []
= "a"
```

So I thought the tail should be the empty List `[]`.

And if you do for example

```
tail ["x"]
```

then you get the empty List `[]`.

This is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the empty string *is* the empty list of `Char`s, it's just `show`n differently:

```
Prelude> [] :: String
""
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the empty `String` and empty list of `Char` are the exact same thing ([`type String = [Char]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:String)). The [`Show` instance for `Char`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Show.html#line-179) takes this into account and overrides the list rendering (using `showList`) to render as strings. This is why there's no [`Show`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Show) instance for `String`; `Show a => Show [a]` handles all lists and uses `showList [Char]`.

As an aside, text is a lot more complex than just a string of characters. That approximation was chosen early on in C and Haskell, but other implementations like [`Data.Text`](http://file:///C:/Program%20Files/Haskell%20Platform/8.2.2/lib/extralibs/doc/text-1.2.2.2/html/Data-Text.html) may have better approaches.

Answer (score 0):

When you define an instance of the Show type class you can implement the method showList, which is the way list of that type are display. So:

```
showList [] = "" -- I guess this is not the actual implementation, but something similar
```

Regards,

Comment: [Something similar.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Show.html#line-179)